# CalDav: Invite another calendar as an attendee

Tags: calendar, icalendar, caldav, sabredav

Does anybody know if it's possible to add a calendar as an attendee?

Here's the scenario.

User has multiple calendars, a calendar object (i.e. event) is added to calendar 1, but we also want it to show on calendar 2. Equally they might add an event to calendar 1, but only want to share it with calendar 3.

Events will always be on calendar 1, but they will usually need to be shared with 1 other calendar.

And then we want to be able to query calendar 2..n and only see the things to which they are invited.

The difficulty being that all these calendars belong to a single user principle.

All the docs and examples I've seen have an email address for the attendee. Is it possible to use the calendar address or something?

FWIW I'm using SabreDav on PHP.